I'm at the fork of the road; should I quit my PhD … again?
I was enrolled in a top university in the faculty of languages and linguistics for my PhD in the spring of ’21 in my home country. Naive, I was unsure of what I wanted to do and with my grades, I decided to take the advice of others who are more experienced in life by signing for the direct to PhD programme from my undergrad. Summing it all up, I had terrible supervisors who were demoralising and self-centred. On top of that, I could not execute a topic that was of my interest, but theirs. With the advice of the deputy dean, she asked me to withdraw from the programme. That was September of ‘23.
Out of rage, I signed up for a PhD programme in another university which started in the beginning of ‘24. This time, they are supervisors whom I worked with during my undergrad. It started off wonderful until recently, the fog has lifted, and reality has set in which I began to realise that the nature of academia—the debates that goes on in what has been written in dissertations or assignments; the time that goes into work that I’m starting to lose interest for; demotivation; and altogether the conflict in which I value real world experiences of solving them there and then, rather than something that can stretch on for years as time is of the essence. It’s only been 6 months in this new institution, but I don’t see a future with me continuing. Neither am I saying that anyone who has completed their PhD did not garner success down the road, nor did they waste their time for some. Everyone’s path is different, but I just feel purposeless staying in the programme. Now, I’m conflicted whether to leave or stay as my folks are telling me about the prestige of a PhD and my supervisors are super nice which I don’t want to let down. I don’t want to regret staying and not pursuing my art which I am fond of, or regret leaving the PhD many years down the road.
Which road should I take?

"I’m conflicted whether to leave or stay as my folks are telling me about the prestige of a PhD and my supervisors are super nice which I don’t want to let down." I have no idea which road you should take, but these are both terrible reasons for staying in a PhD programme. If you genuinely have trouble handling the fact that meaningful research takes time, this in contrast may be an indicator that science is not the path for you. (But I confess that I don't understand what the vague platitude "time is of the essence" means in this context.)

What will you do with a PhD if you earn it? (Note that "become a literature professor" is an extreme long shot.) What will you do for work if you drop out? If the answer to either is "I don't know," recommend you think about that first and then come back.

Prestige is a terrible reason to put yourself through a PhD.  So is not disappointing your supervisors or your family.  I don't say this to be mean or insulting, I promise you.  But I say this very bluntly because it is very important:  You should do a PhD because the colossal effort is worth it to you.  We are often conditioned to think of others before ourselves and this is almost always a wonderful instinct.  But this is one of those times where you simply must consider what you personally want.

Expanding on cag51's comment: you really need to know more about your choices before making a decision. Right now all you have are "I'm unhappy, should I quit?" That's not enough. You need to also know the answers to:

If you quit now, what will you do? ("Option A")
If you don't quit and eventually finish your PhD after several more years of work, what will you do? ("Option B")
What makes you think you'll be happier with Option A than Option B, if you'll be happier at all?
And just to be clear (since we don't know what Option A and B are): what makes you think you'll be happier with Option B than Option A, if you'll be happier at all?

Don't make impulsive decisions. Figure out all your options and work through their consequences as deeply as you can. Remember that ultimately you'll have to earn a living somehow, and whatever else the PhD is, it's a tool towards this end. If the PhD will help you live comfortably, then it makes sense to stay; similarly if the PhD will not help you live comfortably, then it makes sense to quit. But will it actually help you live comfortably? Without first figuring out what options A and B are, you don't know.

Thanks very much for the response. That's good insight and something to visualise on. Only thing that's is clear as for now is that I don't know what I'll be doing with the degree if successfully completed. It was suppose to be left as a fallback plan, but it doesn't sustain the motivation when there isn't a purpose for the degree essentially.
